# Clustered primary key and relations

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm struggeling with the primary keys in my database:

[image: Example 1]

As you can see I use a clustered index. When I try to insert something like:
[image: Example 2]

I get exception that the primary key is duplicated, that is not what I expected. The combination of idQuestionaire and version needs to be unique so that my insert script will work.

I tried the following:
In the "Keys" folder of servey there are 4 keys(the primary, the foreign key from parkinglottype, survey$idQuestionnaire_UNIQUE and survey$version_UNIQUE)

After removing the UNIQUE keys the insert script works fine but my foreign key to surveyquestion does not work anymore...

This is the code of "survey$idQuestionnaire_UNIQUE":

```
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[survey] ADD  CONSTRAINT [survey$idQuestionnaire_UNIQUE] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [idQuestionnaire] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

And here my primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[survey] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_survey_idQuestionnaire] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idQuestionnaire] ASC,
    [version] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

How can I make the clustered Primary Key unique with 2 column and still be able to use it as a foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

If the primary key of "survey" is the *two* columns "idQuestionnaire" and "version", then adding a unique index to "idQuestionnaire" is a mistake. That column alone is *not* unique, as is obvious from both your primary key constraint and your INSERT statement.

SQL Server builds an index on the primary key. Additional indexes on primary key columns are usually not necessary.

Your foreign key constraint needs to reference the *pair* of columns, as `...(Survey_idQuestionnaire, Survey_version) references [dbo].[survey] (idQuestionnaire, version)`.